# How should I maintain a cache of values read from a file?

Tags: java, multithreading, scala, caching

### Setup

There is a program running that is performing arbitrary computations and writing a status (an integer value, representing **progress**) to a file. The integer values can only be incremented.

Now I am developing an other application that can (among other things) perform arithmetic operations, e.g., comparisons, on those integer values. The files are permanently deleted and written by a different program. As such, there is no guarantee that a file exists at any time.

Basically, the application needs to execute something arbitrary, but has a constraint on the other program's progress, i.e., it may only execute something if the other program has done enough work.

### Problem

When performing the arithmetic operations, the application should not care about where the integer values come from. Especially, accessing those integer values must not throw an exception. How should I separate all the bad things that can happen when performing io access?

Note that I do not want the execution thread to block until a value can be read from the file. E.g., say the file system dies somehow, then the integer values will not be updated, but the main thread should still continue to work. This desire is driven by the definition of the arithmetic comparison as a predicate, which has exactly two outcomes, true and false, but no third "error"-outcome. That's why I think that the values that are read from the file would need to be cached somehow.

### Limitation

Java 1.7, Scala 2.11

### Current Approach

I have a solution that looks as if it would work, but I am not sure if there could something go wrong.

The solution is to maintain a cache of those integer values for each file. The core functionality is provided the getters of the cache, while there is a separate "updater"-thread that constantly reads the files and updates the chaches.

If an error occurs the producer should take notice (i.e., log the error), but continue to run, because an incomplete computation should not affect subsequent computations.

A minimal example of what I am currently doing would look something like this:

```
object Application {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val caches = args.map(filename => new Cache(Paths.get(filename))
    val producer = new Thread(new Updater(caches)))
    producer.start()
    execute(caches)
    producer.interrupt()
  }
  def execute(values: Array[AccessValue]) {
    while (values.head.getValue < 5) {/* This should never throw an exception */}
  }
class Updater(caches: Array[Cache]) {
  def run() {
    var interrupted = false
    while(!interrupted) {
      caches.foreach{cache => 
        try {
          val input = Files.newInputStream(cache.file)
          cache.updateValue(parse(input))
        } catch {
          case _: InterruptedException => 
            interrupted = true
          case t: Throwable => 
            log.error(t)
            /*continue as if nothing happend*/
        }
      }
    }
  }
  def parse(input: InputStream): Int = input.read() /* In reality, some xml parsing */
}
trait AccessValue{ 
  def getValue: Int // should not throw an exception
}
class Cache(val file: Path) extends AccessValue{ 
  private val value = 0
  def getValue = value
  def updateValue(newValue: Int) { value = newValue }
}
```

Doing it like this works on a synthetic test setup, but I am wondering whether something bad can happen. Also, if anyone would approach the problem differently, I would be glad to hear how.

- Could there be a throwable that could cause other threads to go wild? I am thinking of something like OutOfMemoryException or StackOverflow. Would I need to handle them differently, or does it not matter, because, e.g., the whole application would die anyways?
- What would happen if the the InterruptException is thrown outside the try block, or even in the catch block? Is there a better way to terminate a thread?
- Must the member value of class Cache be declared volatile? I do not care much about the ordering of reads and write, but the compiler must not "optimize" reading the value away just because it deduces that the value is constant.
- There are a lot of different concurrency-related libraries. Do you suggest me to use something other than new Thread(...).start()? If yes, what facility do you suggest? I know of Scala's ExecutionContext, Future's, and Java's Executors class, which provides various static constructors for thread pools. However, I have never used any of these before and I do not know their advantages and disadvantages. I also stumbled upon the name "Akka", but my guess is that using Akka is overkill for what I want to achieve.

**Thank you**

Comment: How is this problem related to caching?  It's very difficult to understand how your program is intended to work, thus it's very difficult to recommend solutions.

Comment: By caching, I mean that the integer values the core functinonality of the program sees need not be the same as the values that are written in the file at the instance of the lookup. I try to reformulate the question to be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to read through [oracle's documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html) on concurrency.

When one thread writes a value and different thread reads a value, you should always use a synchronized block or declare that value as volatile. Otherwise there is no guarantee that the value written by one thread is visible to the other thread (see [oracle's documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/memconsist.html) on establishing happens-before relationship).

The OutOfMemoryException can influence the other threads as the heap space to which the OutOfMemoryException refers is shared among threads. The StackOverflow exception would kill only the thread in which it occurs because each thread has its own stack.

If you do not need some sort of synchronization between the two threads then you probably do not need any Futures or Executors.